# AngularJS ng-repeat filter function not filtering properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-select2

I have ui-select2 dropdown that depends on the selection of a parent. I have a array of options for the first ui-select2, then when something is selected from that dropdown, the next dropdown will appear. The available options for the 2nd dropdown will depend on what is selected in the first dropdown. The ng-repeat directive is iterating over an array of choices. Here is the html and the js code.

**HTML:**

`<select name="application" placeholder="Select a Tenant"
 ng-disabled="!sharedObj.tenantApplications || 
 sharedObj.tenantApplications.length == null" 
 class="form-control" id="application" 
 ng-change="vmOrderItem.vmNameUSI=null" ui-select2 
 ng-model="vmOrderItem.tenantApplication" title="Select tenant application" 
 data-style="btn-default" required><option></option>
 <option ng-repeat="tenantApplication in sharedObj.tenantApplications |
 filter:tenantFilter()" value="{{tenantApplication.id}}">{{tenantApplication.name}}
 </option>
 </select>`

JS:

```
/** Filters the tenant depending on what domain is selected */
$scope.tenantFilter = function(tenantApplication) {
  $scope.sharedObj.tenantApplications;
  tenantApplication.name;
  tenantApplication.id;
  return true;
  /*    return $scope.vmOrderItem.domain.id == tenantApplication.domainId;*/
}
```

The issue I get is that even if I return true, nothing ever shows up on the dropdown. I did this to test the logic. I don't know why the tenantApplication parameter is always undefined in the function. I used google chrome inspect element to insert a breakpoint and it complains that the argument is undefined. But I don't see why it wouldn't work properly when I return true. I'm a newbie to JavaScript and AngularJS so any help is greatly appreciated. I've worked through all the AngularJS examples and read their docs but I'm still just a beginner.

Comment: Try `filter:tenantFilter` not `filter:tenantFilter()`.

Comment: Thank you Danny, it was the ().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this should be:

```
<option ng-repeat="tenantApplication in sharedObj.tenantApplications |
 filter:tenantFilter" value="{{tenantApplication.id}}">
```

Comment: sorry, just noticed Danny's comment

Comment: It's all good. I wasn't sure that would fix all of his problems, hence why I left it a comment.